# A Brief Introduction

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

I'm certainly not the best in the room
but I do what I can and results are good.
I'm never around for too long in the end,
wouldn't stop for a minute to breathe, if I could.

My color is silver, my place to the left.
Rulers call me their vice, I'm who they rely on.
I'm fleeting and small, hard to track, quick to leave:
If you count to ten I am already gone.

*Who is speaking here?*

Comment: I wrote this yesterday night instead of going to bed. Can you solve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you are:

> **SECOND**

*I'm certainly not the best in the room*
*but I do what I can and results are good.*

> If you come in *second* you are only second best (not *the* best) - but in a wide field of entrants coming second is still a good outcome.

*I'm never around for too long in the end,*
*wouldn't stop for a minute to breathe, if I could.*

> A 'second' is a very short period of time, and certainly much shorter than a minute.

*My color is silver, my place to the left.*

> Second place in many sporting events is rewarded with a *silver* medal. On the winner's [podium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Podium) the silver medallist traditionally stands *to the left* of the winner (as seen face-on by a spectator).

*Rulers call me their vice, I'm who they rely on.*

> '*Second*-in-command' is another word for 'vice', as in 'vice-President' - the person closest to the leader and working to support them in their objectives.

*I'm fleeting and small, hard to track, quick to leave:*
*If you count to ten I am already gone.*

> As in the second (!) rhyming couplet, a second is a small unit of time which passes quickly. Very few people can count out loud to ten without a second elapsing!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for solving it!